# Where to store and how to remove images in a photo gallery?

Tags: asp.net, sql, image, photo

I'm working on a photo gallery using ASP.NET.
I'm storing user's images in a SQL database. I'm not sure how should displaying images look like.

Let's say there is 1 picture per user, I was doing something like that:

- get image from database
- save it on server's disc as "file.jpg"
- ASP:Image.uri = "file.jpg"

And that worked fine until I found out that If few users loads that page at the very same time, It might not work properly.

Then I though changing "file.jpg" into some random string would help me:

- get image from database
- save it on server's disc as "ABCDUDHDJSAKFHADGJKHAKADFAD.jpg"
- ASP:Image.uri = "ABCDUDHDJSAKFHADGJKHAKADFAD.jpg"
- File.Delete("~/ABCDUDHDJSAKFHADGJKHAKADFAD.jpg");

But it wasnt possible to delete this file because it was still being used by a server.

What would be the proper way to solve my problem? User in my photo gallery will eventually see 12 photos at the same time.

Comment: How about using a generic handler and streaming the images in binary form? Then you can just delete the image from the DB, if you need to.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: tip , DO NOT store images in the database.

Comment: I agree with Aviatrix. Don't store images in your database. Try to create a different file location to store the images.

Comment: I will do so, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not store the file actually. You should stream it. For example create a handler which returns the image from an user with a specific ID and call it with that ID like `image.ashx?id=1`. The handler could look like

```
Image image; // image from your database
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.WriteTo(context.Response.OutputStream);
}
Response.ContentType = "image/png";
```

This handler you can use like a static image file. So, you might even use it for a `background-image`:

```
<div style="background-image: url(image.ashx?id=1)">Username</div>
```

Comment: _"You should not store the file actually. You should stream it."_ - what about caching?

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is serve images from DB using a generic handler (`ashx` file).

What you need to do is create an `ashx` file and use something along these lines:

```
context.Response.BinaryWrite(myImage);
```

The you create image tags like so:

```
<img alt="whatever" src="/images.ashx?iid=1243 />
```

Where `iid` is the unique ID of the image in the DB.